# Non static method issue

Tags: android, static-methods

After running a code inspection through android studio, it highlight that the MainHandler should be static. I move the class to static but now it complain that
"Non-Static method remainingSecondsChanged(int) cannot be referenced from a static context"

```
public class CountDownView extends FrameLayout {

    private static void remainingSecondsChanged(int newVal) {
        mRemainingSecs = newVal;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onRemainingSecondsChanged(mRemainingSecs);
        }

        if (newVal == 0) {
            // Countdown has finished.
            setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (mListener != null) {
                mRemainingSecondsView.setText(null);
                mRemainingSecondsView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bracket_view_finder);
                mListener.onCountDownFinished();
            }
        } else {
            Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
            String localizedValue = String.format(locale, "%d", newVal);
            mRemainingSecondsView.setText(localizedValue);

            // Schedule the next remainingSecondsChanged() call in 1 second
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SET_TIMER_TEXT, 1000);
        }
    }

    public void startCountDown(int sec) {
        if (sec < 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (sec == 0) {
            cancelCountDown();
        }
        mRemainingSecondsView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bracket_count_down);
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        remainingSecondsChanged(sec);
    }

    private static class MainHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            if (message.what == SET_TIMER_TEXT) {
                remainingSecondsChanged(mRemainingSecs - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final MainHandler mHandler = new MainHandler();

}
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: You can make `remainingSecondsChanged` static

Comment: @ChungPham I have tried but after the setVisibility, Locale locale = getResources()  are complaining about same issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First... Why's Studio showing that message?

**Background**

Each `Handler` is associated with a `Thread`, and all `Handler` objects on the same `Thread` share a common `Looper` object, where they post and read their messages. Thing is... when these objects are non-static well... non-static inner classes hold an implicit reference to their outer class. So the `Handler` will hold a reference to your `Activity`, and if this `Handler` has a delayed message, your `Activity` will be unable to be garbage collected until this message is processed.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html).

**Solution**

As for your problem. The first thing you already did, which is make your `Handler` a `static` inner class. Now, create a `WeakReference` to your outer class  (Could be an `Activity` or I believe in this case, your `CountDownView`).

Now try changing your `Handler` to something like this (Instead of `Activity` you could reference your `CountDownView`):

```
private static class MainHandler extends Handler {

    private final WeakReference<YourActivity> mActivity;

    public MainHandler(YourActivity activity) {
        mActivity = new WeakReference<YourActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        YourActivity activity = mActivity.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            if (message.what == SET_TIMER_TEXT) {
                activity.remainingSecondsChanged(mRemainingSecs - 1);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

And instantiate it like this:

```
// this is a reference to your Activity, or your CountDownView, wherever your method is.
private final MainHandler mHandler = new MainHandler(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

This StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)  Explains why the inner classes should be static and it is the pretty much same reason why the code analyzer complaints about it,Suppose If you want the members of the containing class to be accessible from your  inner class you can make it non static

Answer (score 0):

I am not android programmer but maybe instead of creating inner class which extends Handler than you can create private field like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      //call your non static method here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of the MainHandler to receive a callback interface

```
public MainHandler(Callback cb){
  this.mCallBack = cb;
}
```

Then at handleMessage call the callback interface to perform the method

```
 public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            if (message.what == SET_TIMER_TEXT) {
                mCallBack.someMethod();1);
            }
        }
```

At fragment declare interface

```
public interface Callback
{
 void someMethod();
}
```

Make your fragment implement it.

```
private final MainHandler mHandler = new MainHandler(this);
```

Then at the implementation call

```
        remainingSecondsChanged(mRemainingSecs - 1);
```

This is not the best way to do it but its the fastest with your current design.